# Do people really pad their arrays for efficient cache access in high-performance computing?

Tags: arrays, caching, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm reading a book on parallel processing called [Intel Xeon Phi Coprocessor High Performance Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124104142). The book recommends that high-performance programs pad array data in order to align heavily used memory addresses for efficient cache line access.

For statically defined arrays, this can be done like so:

```
size_t size = 1024 * 1024;
float buff[size] __attribute__((align(64)));
```

The book also demonstrates how to align dynamically created arrays. Here's an example for a 2D matrix:

```
const size_t kPaddingSize = 64;

int height = 10000;
int width = ((5900 * sizeof(real) + kPaddingSize - 1)/kPaddingSize) * (kPaddingSize/sizeof(real));

size_t size = sizeof(real) * width * kPaddingSize * height;
real *fin = (real *)_mm_malloc(size, kPaddingSize);
real *fout = (real *)_mm_malloc(size, kPaddingSize);

/// ...use the arrays

_mm_free(fin);
_mm_free(fout);
```

Aligning the arrays has real performance benefits. However, coming from my background as a user-facing software developer, the approach seems undesirable for several reasons:

1. The size of the cache line, `kPaddingSize`, is hard-coded in the program.
2. Padding arrays adds a large amount of complexity to the program. Simply creating the arrays is hard enough, but accessing their members is even worse.

I have two questions:

1. How do high-performance application developers mitigate these problems?
2. Is padding arrays a commonplace practice?

Comment: Yes, it's done all the time. Memory access is a frequent bottleneck, and while compilers will often helpfully do this for you for individual scalars or inside structures, for arrays, you will often have to do it on your own.  You see it explicitly done in much GPU programming, for instance, or anywhere else the cycles-to-memory bandwidth ratio is similarly unfavourable.

Comment: Performance and readability is very often a conflicting goal. So you have to pick a point on the trade-off curve and work towards it. Nevertheless, it's possible to make things easier if you're willing to abuse macros and force-inline functions. In this case, a force-inlined operator overload of `[]` might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! You guys should submit answers so I may accept them. Any additional exposition is also appreciated, especially concrete examples of making these sort of performance optimizations more readable.